# Android Custom SeekBar miss conner

Tags: android, android-custom-view, seekbar

I have a customized Seekbar in myproject，it looks fine in the low resolution phone,but miss a conner in high resolution phone.Just like this.

[high resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj6KU.jpg)

[low resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkqCg.png)

here is my xml

```
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sb_lamp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxHeight="6dp"
        android:minHeight="6dp"
        android:max="255"
        android:thumb="@drawable/selector_ic_thumb"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/layer_list_seekbar"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ic_light_stronge"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ic_light_weak" />
```

layer_list_seekbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- background -->
<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_background_back">
</item>

<!-- second progress -->
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
android:drawable="@drawable/ic_background_blue" >
</item>

<!-- progress -->
<item android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_background_blue" >
</item>
```

I have tried to delete `android:thumb="@drawable/selector_ic_thumb"` but still have the problem,so I think there must be something wrong with my layer_layout,
could you please give some advice? thank you!

Comment: change your maxheight to 10 dp. and try it. It is useless if you define both max and min values as same

Comment: Thank you,I have tried you suggestion and it still doesn't work,but I find a way to solve the problem by customize a shape xml  to replace the background picture.